# In magento how to create an attribute to upload an image product page admin

Tags: magento

I need to add a logo image in my product page.To do this i want to create an attribute to upload an image in product page admin.How to create an attribute to upload image in product page and make it to display in front end?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple attribute you can add a new product image type to each products.

A pretty simple example will be here :

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2012/12/adding-a-fourth-image-position-to-the-admin-for-a-magento-product/

Hope this helps

Update

you just need to call this inside helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'brandimage')->resize(400,300); ?>">

Comment: Hi I have tried this link but it is not working.I have uploaded the image in admin and chosen the respective radio button and updated the code in this file app\design\frontend\default\Mytheme\template\catalog\product\view.phtml.But in front end i am not getting the image instead i am getting the hardcode path of that image.@SKV

Comment: Hi this is the image path i am getting in front end.http://localhost/magentosample/media/catalog/product/cache/1/brandimage/400x300/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/b/tbb-logo-160-px-x-160-px-low-res.jpg

Comment: you just need to call this inside <img tag as ex follows : <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'brandimage')->resize(400,300); ?>">

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45811/discussion-between-rama-priya-and-skv)

Answer (score 0):

I think below link can help you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/file-attributes.html

This extension enables us to upload file for a product. I think this can be used to upload image as well.

Hope this may help you...

Comment: link is not opening :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upload the files in product page tab, no need to create the product custom attribute. just install the following extension

Then php bin/magento setup:upgrade php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB php bin/magento indexer:reindex php bin/magento cache:clean

working perfectly.

https://github.com/Sebwite/Magento2-Product-Downloads/tree/2.1-dev